# cómo crear relaciones muchos a muchos laravel/voyager?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

estuve investigando pero no encuentro la forma de crear relaciones muchos a muchos usan voyager en laravel, les agradecería si alguien pudiera explicarme o tenga alguna guía que me proporcione. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: existen varios ejemplos en su pagina oficial, no creo que hayas "investigado", te dejo el [ink de la pagina oficial](https://laravel.com/)

Comment: Pero utilizando voyager?... Directamente en laravel si lo sé hacer amigo.. saludos

Comment: nunca utilize voyager, pero dudo mucho que sea diferente ademas tiene su [documentacion](https://laravelvoyager.com/docs/)